# collectionView not reloading in parentviewcontroller on removal of childviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, reload

Any one know how to reload `collectionView` in `parentViewController` when removing `childViewController`.

Here, I am processing on click of button adding `childViewController` and on click of that `childViewController` I am getting data and that data will transferred to `parentViewController` after that child view get's remove from `parentViewController`.

I am getting data from `childViewController`, also reloading collection view.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    [self.collectionViewcellItem layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.collectionViewcellItem reloadData];
});
```

but, no effect of reloading here seen.
means not able to change parentviewconroller view after removal of `childViewController`.

Thank you 
Waiting for the answer and yes I am doing it in objective c.

`parentViewController` file.

```
[self.view addSubview:filterMenuVC.view];
filterMenuVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self addChildViewController:filterMenuVC];

[self.view addSubview:filterMenuVC.view];

[self animationSideFilterMenuBarOpen];

[filterMenuVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

`childViewController` file

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row]);

    //   // [wel animationSideFilterMenuBarClose];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    int categoryId = (int)cell.textLabel.tag;

    [self animationSideMainMenuBarClose:categoryId];



}
-(void)animationSideMainMenuBarClose:(int)categoryId{

    CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(width - self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(width, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                         self.view = nil;


                         NSLog(@"category id Filter: %d",categoryId);
                         BOOL boolresponse = [wel getUserWork:categoryId];
                         if (boolresponse == NO) {
                             UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                          message:@"No internet connection"
                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                             UIAlertAction *okButton = [UIAlertAction
                                                        actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                                        }];


                             [alert addAction:okButton];


                             [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                         }
                     }];


}
```

here, `BOOL boolresponse = [wel getUserWork:categoryId];` getUserWork is the function in parentViewController, I call that and removing the `childViewController`. get correct data but not able to reload collectionView.

`parentViewFunction` which I am calling.

```
  -(BOOL)getUserWork:(int)catergoryId{
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^{
        //do whatever you do here
        [self.collectionViewcellItem reloadData];
    }];


    categoryIdStart = catergoryId;

    Reachability *r = [[Reachability alloc]init];

    if(r.currentReachabilityStatus != NotReachable)  {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {


        [SVProgressHUD show];
        [SVProgressHUD setStatus:@"Loading..."];
        [SVProgressHUD setRingRadius:20];
        [SVProgressHUD setRingThickness:10];
        [SVProgressHUD setBorderColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        [SVProgressHUD setBorderWidth:0.5];
        [SVProgressHUD setForegroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

        NSLog(@"id category: %d",categoryIdStart);
        NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[appDelegate.UserDic valueForKey:@"token"],@"token",[appDelegate.UserDic valueForKey:@"id"],@"id_user",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",categoryIdStart],@"id_category",nil];

        NSMutableArray *postArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [params enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
            [postArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, [apiCall percentEscapeString:obj]]];
        }];
        NSString *postString = [postArray componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

        [apiCall apiType:@"xyzzy" pD:postString dataRetrive:^(NSDictionary *dictionary){

            int status = [[dictionary  valueForKey:@"status"] intValue];
            if (status == 0) {

                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                 message:[dictionary valueForKey:@"msg"]
                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                    UIAlertAction *okButton = [UIAlertAction
                                               actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

                                               }];


                    [alert addAction:okButton];


                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

                });
            }
            else{

                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];



                    [cacheImage removeAllObjects];

                    dic = [dictionary valueForKey:@"data"];

                    NSLog(@"Category detail: %@ %lu",dic,(unsigned long)dic.count);


                    NSLog(@"image category %@ :",[dic valueForKey:@"category_name"]);




                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{



                    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                     [self.collectionViewcellItem layoutIfNeeded];
                    [self.collectionViewcellItem reloadData];


                        [self viewWillAppear:true];

                });


            }
        }];

        return YES;
    }




}
```

Comment: Show us complete code of where u calling this method, how are u passing data from childVC to parent etc. BTW simplest way to handle is call reload data in ViewWillAppear of ParentVC

Comment: Hello, @SandeepBhandari edited the question as per you said. Thank you for helping.

Comment: you can use viewWillAppear to reload collectionView. but it is better to use delegate to reload collectionview on dismiss

Comment: @aashish-bapodra : Do u dismiss/pop out the childViewController in parent VC's `getUserWork` method? Because the code that you have in ChildVC will not remove it from parentVC all it does is sets it view to nil hope u have code for dismissing childVC in parentVC

Comment: @Mohammadalijf  On removal of childViewController, I debug and found that viewWillAppear not calling of parentViewController on removal of ChildViewController.

Comment: @aashish-bapodra : Thats because from your code in `animationSideMainMenuBarClose` I can only see that you are setting the childVC 's view to nil but not dismissing it. Had you dismissed it your alert would have never been presented :)

Comment: did you use container view to display childController's view? if so you should definitely use delegates

Comment: @SandeepBhandari - I am using [self.view removeFromSuperview]; code. so I think all view get remove from paretnViewController. I don't know how to dismiss childviewcontroller.

Comment: @aashish-bapodra : These two statements `[self.view removeFromSuperview]; self.view = nil;` are pretty much useless in your case :) Lemme update answer wait

Comment: @Mohammadalijf - Yes, I used container, but I tried delegate method it's not allowing me to do it delegate method. it's says me to that no protocol found of class. I setup all the things.

Comment: @aashish-bapodra : Take a look at the answer below